# extracting the 4 byte of char from char string and convert the first 4 byte to integer in c

Tags: c

I have a string such as `char *x = "1234 is a test";` where the first 4 chars are hex digits that I need to extract as an integer.

My approach is to extract the first 4 chars:

```
char dest[5];
strncpy(dest, x,4);
char dest[5]='\0';
```

How can I convert this 4-char string to `int`?

I have tried using `strtol(dest, &ptr,16 );`, but `strtol` finds and converts numerical values.

It appears that the string is obtained from network; thus without using `strtol`, I suppose to use hex to decimal conversion.  I need to first pack 4 chars into an `int` type and use this.

How can I coalesce these 4 char to `int`?

Comment: To begin with, change `char[5]='\0'` to `dest[4]='\0'`. Then, when calling `strtol`, I suppose you meant to pass `dest` (what is `str`?).

Comment: Is `1234` *hex* data (in which case your `strtol()` should work fine), or *binary* data representing a four-byte `int`?

Comment: @DevSolar: How can `"1234"` be binary data representing a four-byte `int`???

Comment: No idea, his question doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: `char dest[5]='\0'; ` why you declared again `dest[]` and assigning `\0` to 5th index?

Comment: @DevSolar: I think OP simply can't find a way to make his/her code work as they want it to, that's all.

Comment: Please clarify: Should code 1) read up to 4 hexadecimal characters as a C string and convert to an `int` or 2) read 4 bytes packed as a 4-byte `int`?

Answer (score 1):

```
 char *x = "1234 is a test";
```

Depending on whether you can **rely** on the fifth character not being a hex digit, you might skip the copying, and aim `strtol()` at `x` directly. It will stop parsing at the first character that is not a valid digit in the base you selected.

If you cannot rely on that, your copying code needs some cleaning up: `char dest[5]` declares an array with *five* elements, indices **0** through **4**, so `dest[5] = '\0';` would be setting a non-existent **sixth** element to zero, resulting in undefined behaviour. The digits will reside in `dest[0]` through `dest[3]` after copying, so it is really `dest[4]` that you would want to zero.

And drop the `char` in `char dest[4] = '\0';`, otherwise you are redeclaring `dest`...

```
char dest[5];
strncpy( dest, x, 4 );
dest[4] = '\0';
```

Somewhat more elegant would be:

```
char dest[5] = { 0 }; // actually sets *all* elements to zero
memcpy( dest, x, 4 );
```

> i have tried using strtol(dest, &ptr,16 );

That should have worked, really. You did not show the code; from your comments that `strtol()` "finds the numerical values and seperates", I assume you were confused a bit and looked at `ptr` for the result. That is just a pointer at where `strtol()` stopped parsing. The *result* is *returned* by `strtol()`:

```
char * ptr;
int i = strtol( dest, &ptr, 16 );
```

If you are not interested in the end pointer, you can just pass `NULL`:

```
int i = strtol( dest, NULL, 16 );
```

---

If, indeed, the first 4 bytes are *not* hex digits at all, but the *binary* representation of an `int` (which your last paragraph edited in later *seems* to imply), the way to go about it would be a `union`.

```
union
{
    int ival;
    char cval[4];
} convert;

memcpy( &convert.cval, x, 4 );

int i = convert.ival;
```

This is, of course, assuming that `sizeof( int ) == 4` and that receiver has the same byte order (endianness) as the sender.. If not, you're in trouble, `unions` are tricky that way.

Comment: This answer is 50% fixing unrelated (?) bugs and 50% crystal ball divination. Next time, please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming first byte is the most significant byte:

```
int convert_char(char c) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return c - '0';
    }
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
        return (10 + c - 'A');
    }
    else  if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
        return (10 + c - 'a');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
char *x = "1234 is a test";
int y = 0;
y = convert_char(x[0]) * 16 * 16 * 16 + convert_char(x[1]) * 16 * 16 + convert_char(x[2]) * 16 + convert_char(x[3]);
```

Comment: Why would we want to reimplement (part of) the standard function the OP is already using in a non-portable way?